# Xcode: Tab Bar App with different pages on each tab

Tags: ios, tabbar

I have a tab bar application with 4 tabs, on one of the tabs I would like a simple guide with 5 steps, each step will have its own view with a button to go to the next step and back to the previous step via segues between views. When I make a transition from the first step to the second step the view loses the tab bar. Do I need to implement a solution where only part of the view is transitioned to display the next step? or can you have transitions while keeping the tab bar on every screen?

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: How are you pushing the views when moving from a step to the next step?

Comment: I'm using storyboard and I'm just using a button to go from one viewcontroller to the next and another button to return to the previous one. Using a modal transition

Comment: What sort of transitions do you want? The solution that springs to mind here is to use a UIPageViewController with its transition style set to scroll - that would be a natural paradigm for a five-step guide. I'm using this setup (tab bar controller + page view controller) in a current project and it works fine.

Comment: I've tried looking into a UIPageViewController but I can't find any useful guides on how to implement it. Do you know of any?